# Is there any similar script to DSUM formula in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm usually using a DSUM formula for sum based on multiple criteria on my Google Sheet.

But today, I have a plan to migrate using Google Apps Script. Is there any script that similar to DSUM formula? Or any reference such as YouTube or something else.

Thanks

Comment: Probably not. You have to create one yourself.  See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: Alright then. Thank you for reference